# Custom UITableViewCell not updating

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

so basically I have a custom UITableViewCell (In this case a simple cell with a UIImageView set in the middle) which is properly subclassed (I have a .h .m file for the cell and the image view is properly "outletted").

On loading the cell, I need to be able to change the UIImageView into a circle as well as add a gesture recogniser to the UIImageView (so that if a user taps on the ImageView, it will load up an UIImagePicker - allowing users to set an image).

The problem I am facing is that, although the code is executed according to the debugger, the UI is never updated - (I still see a generic square UIImageView and the gesture recogniser does not work).

Here is the code for the cellforrowatindexpath delegate method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row==0 && indexPath.section==0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Profile Cell";
        Profileviewcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[Profileviewcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.ProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.ProfileImage.bounds.size.width/2;
        cell.ProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [cell.ProfileImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LoadImage:)];
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tap.delegate = self;
        [cell.ProfileImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [cell setNeedsDisplay];
        return cell;
    } else {
        //return a standard cell 
    }
}
```

I have also tried putting the same code in the willdisplaycell delegate method (along with a  [cell setNeedsdisplay] but that is not working either.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row==0 && indexPath.section==0) {
        Profileviewcell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.ProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.ProfileImage.bounds.size.width/2;
        cell.ProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [cell.ProfileImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LoadImage:)];
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tap.delegate = self;
        [cell.ProfileImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    }

}
```

Initwithstyle code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.ProfileImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110,5,100,100)];
        [self.ProfileImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"General Profile"]];
        self.ProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.ProfileImage.bounds.size.width/2;
        self.ProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [self.ProfileImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.ProfileImage];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Any ideas as to why the cell UI is never updating? I have checked Stack Overflow for similar problems and every solution provided doesn't seem to work for me. Apologies if this is a simple question - I have only recently started iOS development.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Is `cell.ProfileImage` equal to `nil` when modifying its `layer` and adding the gesture recognizer? If so, that would account for the issue you are having.

Comment: @bobnoble Many thanks for the reply! Yes it is nil according to the debugger, but I am not exactly sure why! The cell is a prototype cell in storyboard and I have created a subclass of a UITableViewCell in Xcode as well. How would I stop it being nil (and why is it nil in the first place?)?

Comment: Show the code for the custom `UITableViewCell`, especially where `ProfileImage` is declared and how it is initialized as part of the `initWithStyle` method.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellForIdentifier:` will always return a valid cell. You don't need to check if it's `nil`.

Comment: @bobnoble Apologies for the late reply - I have edited the original question to include the initwithStyle method (it was too large to post here) - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue, turns out I needed to move all the code to the initwithstyle function of the subclass and most importantly **synthesise** the UIImageView in the header of the subclass (unfortunately, I made the rookie error of forgetting this which meant that the ImageView just remained null).

Hope this is helpful for others with the same problem!

Thanks to all those who helped though!

Answer (score 0):

Very likely your image outlet is `nil` when you try to modify it.

Please note that it is a convention to have the names of class properties start with a small letter - otherwise it is easy to mistake them for class names. So `cell.profileImage` (based on
`@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImage;`)
is more appropriate.

Also, you can scrap the `if (cell==nil)` block and the `setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: Thankyou, I will change the code to match this - never knew that! Yes it is an issue with the image outlet being nil, but I have no clue why it is nil as I have (tried) to declare and instance it :)

Comment: Make sure the image view is hoooked up in the Xib/Storyboard file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going on here...

1. As stated by others, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always
   returns a valid `UITableViewCell` so the `nil` check always returns
   `NO` meaning the custom cell's `initWithStyle` is never invoked, and
   thus `ProfileImage` is never instantiated, which is why it is equal
   to `nil`.
2. Currently there are three places where there is code to modify the
   `ProfileImage` layer (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `willDisplayCell`,
   and the custom cell's `initWithStyle`). The last one seems like the
   right place for this.
3. I suspect in the storyboard, the class of the custom cell is not set
   (i.e., says `UITableViewCell`) but should be the name of your custom
   cell.

Recommend:

- Removing the configuring of the `ProfileImage` layer from the
  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and removing the `willDisplayCell` method.
- Remove the `nil` check in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
- Set the class of the storyboard cell to the name of your custom cell

Comment: Thanks again, I have implemented all the changes you suggested. The code was a bit scrappy and repeated because I copied the code in multiple functions to try and see what the issue was. Turns out I should have looked in the subclass first (forgot to synthesise the UIImageView)! Many thanks for your help!